# Combining legends for two different aesthetics fails

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- data.frame(Specimen=c("A","B","C","D"), Value=rep(0.5,4), 
                 Type=c("c1","c1","c2","c2"), Treatment=factor(rep("A", 4)),
                bar=c("hot", "cold", "cold", "cold"))

list2env(split(x, x$Type), envir = .GlobalEnv)
p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=c1, aes(x = Treatment, y = Value, fill = Specimen, colour=bar), 
           stat="identity", position="fill", width=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual("",values=c("gold", "green"))+
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("gray40","black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  coord_flip()    


p2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=c2, aes(x = Treatment, y = Value, fill = Specimen), 
           stat="identity", position="fill", col="gray40", width=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual("",values=c("red", "blue"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
  xlab("")+
  coord_flip()

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1,p2, nrow=1, align="v")
```

[image]

In this example, i had to shut down the guide for color, as i couldnt combine it with the  guide for fill, despite following the guidelines proposed in this question.
After turning off the guide for `col` in p1 (`guide=F`), the legends now appear to be differently drawn (one with `col="gray40"`, the other without any border, as the col-guide is set to false):
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrQyu.png)

How to combine the two legends in p1?

Comment: What should the desired combined legend look like?

Comment: Keys "A" and "B" should have the borders drawn as specified in scale_col_manual (A is "hot", "B" is cold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill` and `color` are mapped to two different varaibles, it's only by chance that in this (trivial) case "A" is always "hot" and "B" is always "cold".

You can map both fill and color to `Specimen` or `bar`, but different variable will always result in different legends.

An alternative may be to create an interaction between the two varaibles:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data=c1, aes(x = Treatment, 
                        y = Value, 
                        fill = interaction(Specimen, bar, sep = '-'), 
                        color = interaction(Specimen, bar, sep = '-')), 
           position="fill", width=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual("",values=c("gold", "green")) +
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("gray40", "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you so far. Is it possible to write only A and B to the keys, and suppress the factor levels of the color-variable?

Comment: add `labels = c('B', 'A')` to both `scales_*_manual`. Are you sure you don't just want to assign `Specimen` to both `color` and `fill` `aes`?

Comment: I am pretty close to what i want to achieve with "interaction". Its however messing up the factor level ordering. I want to order it by Specimen, but its currently ordered by bar. (My real example is a lot bigger at 20 levels for Specimen, and two levels for bar)-